# Advance layout with pseudo classes

Tags: html, css

So the question is...

Good css rules:
We have to set top/right or bottom/right or top/left or bottom/left for `position: absolute`.
instead of margin...

But do we have to set thouse positions for css `::after` or `::before`??

Pseudo-classes always goes after or before the element.

If, so.. how to reach expecting output like that:

```js
$(function(){
$('span').on('click',function(){
$(this).parent().append(' extra text ');
})
})
```

```css
.test__block{
    width:200px;
    margin:20px;
    border:2px solid;
    position:relative;
}

#blue{
    border-color:blue;}

#red{
    border-color:red}

span{
    cursor:pointer;
    font-weight:800}

#blue:after {
      content: "+";
      font-size:16px;
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: 0;
      margin-top: -4px;
      color:orange;
}
    
#red:after {
      content: "+";
      font-size:16px;
      position: absolute;
      left: 80px;
      top: 30px;
      color:orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='blue' class='test__block'>Blue text with after element, position set to absolute and top/left, <span>add</span></div>
<div id='red' class='test__block'>Red text with after element, position set to absolute and margin, <span>add</span></div>
```

So, if you press add button you will see how '+' react with component.

Expecting effect is a blue container.

So what is a propper way to do that? It is only a example. The thing is i will not add text but text will have diferent dimension on each component, so adding different position to after element each time will be pointless? or maybe someday content will change and i will have to set thouse each time? 
What if i will have to set thouse for 100? or 1 000 comonents?

Any clue?!

Comment: *Expecting effect is a blue container.* --> you have the solution then? what is exactly the issue

Comment: The thing is.  To set element with position absolute it is nessesery to set horizontal and verdical position, for keeping same result in different browsers, good practice. But in my point of view pseudo-classes as, ::after set thouse poistion for as dinamicly. But im not shure :D

Answer (score 1):

`::after` is a pseudo element which allows you to insert content onto a page from CSS (without it needing to be in the HTML). While the end result is not actually in the DOM, it appears on the page as if it is.

`::before` is exactly the same only it inserts the content before any other content in the HTML instead of after. The only reasons to use one over the other are:

- You want the generated content to come before the element content,
  positionally.
- The `::after` content is also "after" in source-order, so it will
  position on top of `::before` if stacked on top of each other naturally.

The other thing you concern about is the position of it. Try to make `$(this).parent().append(' extra text ');` to `$(this).parent().append(' extra text extra text extra text extra text extra text');`. The `+` will remain in the same position (according to blue one) and if you click `add`, it will still be the end of the text. Because when you set `margin-left` and `margin-top` values to blue one, you are setting the positions of `+` on `span`.

So when you're adding the text to that `span` element and click `add`, the text will expand and the `+` will always come `::AFTER` the text with given positions, no matter what. Because of pseudo classes. The vertical and horizontal positions you set on `::after` is the position of after the element.

> An **absolutely positioned element** is an element whose computed position value is `absolute` or `fixed`. The `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` properties specify offsets from the edges of the element's containing block. (The containing block is the ancestor relative to which the element is positioned.) If the element has margins, they are added to the offset.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: So, in your point of view not giving a horizontal and vertical position for pseudo-classes with position absolute is acceptable, and thouse values are not nessesery when we use pseudo-class.

Comment: No, giving horizontal and vertical position sets the position of `:after`. You add `+` after the element, and positions comes after the element. If you delete `margin-top: -4px;`, `+` will align differently. Try change the positions and you'll see the difference.

Comment: Come one... i know if i will change margin position will change. But as you can see i did not set horizontal and verdical position on absolute element, i just set margin. Question is if i wont set top/left position it will be bad practice? or i did not have to set them pod after elements?

Comment: No it won't be a bad practice. You don't have to use them every time. It depends on the situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the same `position` declarations to a `pseudo-element` as you can to an `element`:

- `position: static`
- `position: relative`
- `position: absolute`
- `position: fixed`
- `position: sticky`

*On the whole*, in order to establish complete control over your positioning of the `pseudo-element` I would suggest it ***is*** good practice to apply `position: relative` to the parent element (if it doesn't already have a non-static `position` declaration applied to it) and then apply `position: absolute` and co-ordinates to the child `pseudo-element`.